# How to import module in nodejs from some external file

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I have this file `indexjs` where I am exporting data

```
exports.updateMobileNumber = updateMobileNumber;
```

and in my appjs I am importing it.

```
var index = require('./../helpers/index');
```

Now another file mainjs is on external URL like

`https://github.com/../models/catalog/main.js`

How to import this file in my appjs

*I don't want to download the file* as it has its own server. Is it possible to make `http` request from one nodejs to another nodejs running simultaneously so that I get the required value. If yes, please help how to do it!

**I have 1st node running at 3000 and another running at 3003, what should be the next step?**

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way of doing this, and for good reason - executing code from a remote server is a pretty bad idea! What's the use case here?

Comment: there are some validation like mobile number validation, otp verification, mail verification so I want to keep it in separate file so this won't be disturbed while running code.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there's a way to do this. You could `GET` a remote JSONP file, but NodeJS files must be locally accessible.

Comment: you can of course "download" or request the file by an url  but as already mentioned this is most of the time not a convenient way.

Comment: if we are talking about data, it's the correct way using http module inside node for requesting remote data files.

Comment: True @JackBlack, data requests remotely are fine, and are needed for REST operations. `require` is synchronous, so it couldn't load remote files for execution anyway.

Comment: To the OP, I updated my post; to reiterate you can make a HTTP request for data, but not code... and not using `require`.

Comment: @Defiant could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: @Sumit you could expose the file using a route on one server, e.g. to have the url `127.0.0.1:3000/mainFile` and then get it on your other node instance using a `GET` request to that route. This way you would be using HTTP. Does this make sense?

Comment: sounds pretty cool..let me check!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer for the bare question (as it's written in title):

**Download the file and place it inside your project, so you can use it with require.**

--

You should think about: (as already mentioned in a lot of comments):

1. If your remote file is data only (most of the time json) it's a convenient and correct way requesting the file via http, save it and then use it with require again!

   **more about http inside node:**

   - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback
   - https://github.com/request/request
2. If the remote file **is not about data only** and you thought about executing remote code - it's the wrong way! think about it! your remote file is in your case a kind of a "vendor library / util / helper" which you should implement strictly in awareness. (keywords: npm, modularization, vendors, helpers)

Answer (score 2):

`NPM` is designed for you to install and manage remote modules. Modules must be locally accessible and installed when a NodeJS instance is started up.

If you `require` a module not known to your `package.json` file, an error will be thrown.

**Edit:** `require` is synchronous, so it can't load non-local files (which would be an asynchronous operation). You could load data asynchronously though, using `request`.